# In Psalm 27, David appears to request more than one thing. Why does he say the word "One"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tehilim-psalms

Psalms 27:4:

> **אַחַ֤ת** ׀ שָׁאַ֣לְתִּי מֵֽאֵת־יְהוָה֮ **אוֹתָ֪הּ** אֲבַ֫קֵּ֥שׁ שִׁבְתִּ֣י
>   בְּבֵית־יְ֭הוָה כָּל־יְמֵ֣י חַיַּ֑י לַחֲז֥וֹת בְּנֹֽעַם־יְ֝הוָ֗ה
>   וּלְבַקֵּ֥ר בְּהֵיכָלֽוֹ׃

Modified Sefria.com translation:

> **One** thing have I asked of the LORD, **it** will I seek after: a) That I may
>   dwell in the house of the LORD all the days of my life, b) To behold the
>   pleasantness of the LORD, and c) to visit early in His temple.

It seems that he is requesting 3 things (which I marked a, b, c) above. Why does David use the term "one thing" and "it"?

Comment: It seems obvious that the answer is that "b" and "c" are not additional reasons besides "a". For example, they can be seen as the _reason_ for requesting "a". The Psalmist requests to dwell in the abode of God, so that he may perceive God and frequent his sanctuary.

Comment: BTW I dont know how וּלְבַקֵּ֥ר implies being early.

Comment: @mevaqesh I left this translation there despite Sefaria's poor translation, in general. There is a MY question and answer on this, asked last week. Rashi has one translation which means "in the morning", so using the term "early" is not the most accurate, but, I think, fits the context of this translation. If I find the link to that MY question, I'll put in another comment, but you can easily locate Rashi's comment on this verse. Re - your 1st comment -  I think that my analysis is also possible. IIRC, there is some Midrash that may explain this, but I don't recall who or where.

Comment: @mevaqesh Done. Thanks for the reminder. I guess there's a reason for your ID :-o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metzudas David thereon apparently understands "b" and "c" to be the same thing.

> לחזות. לראות בנעימות תורת ה' : ולבקר. לדרוש בהיכלו בדבר מצות ה'

Furthermore, Malbim understands "b" and "c" to be the reason for the request "a"; not requests in and of themselves.

> שבתי בבית ה' כל ימי חיי, הוא על הכוונה כדי לחזות בנועם ה' ולבקר בהיכלו, ואין בלבי כונה אחרת

Answer (score 1):

Art Scroll translates b and c to imply "in order to".

Thus the translatoion reads.

```
One thing that I asked of Hashem;
 that shall I seek:
That I dwell in the House of Hashem
  all the days of my life.
[in order] To behold the delight of Hashem
  and to  meditate in His Sanctuary.
```

Note the spacing used as part of the translation. Thus, Art Scroll is translating it as a single request which will allow one to have the two things whichresult from "dwelling in the House of Hashem"